# How to define new commands in emacs

Tags: emacs

I keep forgetting emacs terminology for Select All, so I'd like to add a new emacs command so that I can type M-x select-all RET and have it run mark-whole-buffer.

I tried adding this to my .emacs file:

(defun select-all () (mark-whole-buffer))

or this:

(defun select-all () (interactive) (mark-whole-buffer))

But these don't seem to put the names in the right "namespace" to be access via M-x, how do I get them in the right namespace?

Thanks,
-Shawn

Comment: Oops, looks like this was my fault, the (interactive) version does work as written.

Comment: "Select All" can also be found in the Edit menu, at least in EmacsW32.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(interactive)` tells Emacs that the function is a command, i.e. that the function can be bound to a key and executed with `M-x`.
So

```lisp
(defun select-all ()
  (interactive)
  (mark-whole-buffer))
```

should work (but `(defun select-all () (mark-whole-buffer))` won't). Did you restart Emacs or evaluate the definition with `C-M-x` (`eval-defun`)? What does `C-h f select-all RET` show? (The help buffer should begin with “select-all is an interactive”.)

Here, a simpler alternative is

```
(defalias 'select-all 'mark-whole-buffer)
```

Comment: Great defalias sounds like exactly what I'm going for. In fact defun works for me now again, somebody in the office changed a file I was loading and broke my whole .emacs file (that's why defun didn't work originally). Thanks all!

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is already built in:

```
M-x mark-whole-buffer
```

bound to

```
C-x h
```

But, to get what you want by writing something, your second implementation works for me just fine, and I can get to it by typing <kbd>M-x</kbd>.

Comment: Like I said, I always forget what emacs calls this command, so I'm trying to make an alias. I'll give it another try, maybe I failed to load it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The one with the interactive looks like it's correct, and it works for me.... did you remember to re-load your .emacs after defining it?

Comment: Yes, I did try reloading, but someone in the office broke a file I loaded and so my whole .emacs wasn't loading. Thanks for checking it!